# div под div в html не ставится из-за align left

Tags: html, позиционирование

Всем привет! Пробую разместить один `div` под другим. Проблема в том, что внутри `div` есть фото, у которого есть атрибут `align="left"`. `div` залезает в `div` внутрь и я не могу понять почему, и как это исправить.

```html
<div class="restaurant">
  <img class="image" width="150px" height="150px" align="left" src="" />
  <div>
    <a class="link" href="https://samara.maximilians.ru/">Максимилианс</a>
    <br> Московское ш, 4
    <br>
    <font color="#666">11:00 - 02:00</font>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="restaurant">
  <img class="image" width="150px" height="150px" align="left" src="" />
  <div>
    <a class="link" href="https://samara.maximilians.ru/">Максимилианс</a>
    <br> Московское ш, 4
    <br>
    <font color="#666">11:00 - 02:00</font>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zgsL415q/24/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`align="left"` похож на обтекание, добавьте к restaurant `clear: both;`

Comment: Ура!! Спасибо))